# Why is the Acceleration vs Mass graph curved and not straight?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

The graph representing Acceleration vs Force (Mass constant):-

[image]

The graph representing Force vs Mass (Acceleration constant):-

[image]

The graph representing Acceleration vs Mass (Force constant):-

[image]

Why is it that the first two graphs are straight lines, but not the third one? What is inherently different about the relationship between Acceleration and Mass (or any two variables, for that matter) that results in their graphs being curved and not straight?

Comment: What if you write Newton's second law and solve for the ordinate as a function of abscissa for each graph? You should be able to see where the function is linear and where the proportionality is inverse, which would be the case of a hyperbolic curve.

Comment: Writing these charts in the form $Y=g(X)$ for suitable choices of a function $g$, we get $Y=m^{-1}X,\,Y=mX,\,Y=FX^{-1}$ because $F=ma$.

Comment: my questions are 1) why label the axes $(X, Y)$ , and not just $(F, m)$, $(F, a)$,.... 2) why aren't the, ahem, $y-$intercepts $0$?

Answer (score 1):

We know from Newton's Second Law that

$F = ma$

So for constant mass $m$ we have $F \propto a$ which means the graph of $F$ against $a$ is a straight line through the origin.

And for constant acceleration $a$ we have $F \propto m$ which means the graph of $F$ against $m$ is a straight line through the origin.

But for constant force $F$ we have $a \propto \frac 1 m$ which means the graph of $a$ against $m$ is *not* a straight line - it is a hyperbola. However, the graph of $a$ against $\frac 1 m$ will be a straight line through the origin.

Answer (score 0):

In the first 2 graphs Acceleration or mass are constant . By second law of motion F=ma now since in third graph mass and acceleration varries F is constant, therefore this equation turns to a xy=c graph of rectangular hyperbola
.